# How to make the entire website support 'www' and 'non-www' with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just moved my site to a new server and this is Mac OS X server

the problem is that I don't have much control with it and there is one little problem [or maybe big for others]

When people visit my site `http://mydomain.com` this will work fine with or without `www` but I've another folder in a sub directory called `forum` and the only want to visit this site is to go like `http://www.mydomain.com/forum` and when I visit `http://mydomain.com/forum` it will result page not found and my current solution is to create a directory in the folder `www` where my site locate with a folder called `forum` with redirection to `http://www.mydomain.com/forum`

Now my question is how can I create a rewrite rule to .htaccess to make it support both version of www and non-www so that the visitors will have an option to visit my site.

Sorry if I post in the wrong place.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot            /u02/web/hosting/domain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=Permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com        
    DocumentRoot            /u02/web/hosting/www.domain.com
....
</VirtualHost>
```

First vhosts just redirect all traffic from domain.com to second vhosts www.domain.com

Comment: I thought of this solution, but it won't work because he probably wants the `domain.com` not to do an external redirect, but just to work as an alternate name for the website, but with reduced functionality (block attempts to access the `/forum` that way). Though a 301 redirect might be a better way to handle accesses to `example.com/forum` rather than 404-ing them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin the cat, but my instinct says that two different domains with different behaviors should be different `VirtualHost` entries, possibly with different document roots.

In this case I would make two virtual hosts pointing to the same `DocumentRoot` since for the most part `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` are the same site, except that `example.com` wants to disallow some things.

The `VirtualHost` for `http://example.com` can look for specific URL's like `/forum` and fail them, allowing the others to pass on to accessing the document root.

The `VirtualHost` for `http://www.example.com` does not care about any of that; it just allows normal access to its URL.